# get all children recursively using a mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using the express framework with mongoose, and I have the following Schema:

```
var DocumentSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    parent: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Document"
    },
    children: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Document'
    }]
});
```

I'm trying to get a dynamic hierarchy tree of children but I could not find any suitable solution.

Is it possible to do that using this schema? If not, what schema structure should I should use ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by hierarchy tree of children. An example of the desired data output would be helpful.

If you need to load all of the descendants of a particular node using your schema into a flat structure you can use something like this:

```
getAllChildNodes(startNodeId, callback) {
  const tree = [];
  let idsToLoad = [];

  yourModel.findOne({_id: startNodeId }).exec((err, node) => {
    tree.push(node);
    idsToLoad = node.children;
    let count = 0;

    async.whilst(
      () => {
        return count < idsToLoad.length
      },
      (cb) => {
        yourModel.findOne({_id: idsToLoad[count] }).exec((err, doc) => {
          tree.push(doc);
          idsToLoad = idsToLoad.concat(doc.children);
          count++;
          cb();
        });
      },
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return callback(err);
        }
        return callback(null, tree);
      }
    );

  });
}
```

This can be a pretty expensive query and not very efficient. I would not recommend this schema type if this is a primary use case for you. I would look into using [Materialized Paths](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/) or [Nested Sets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-nested-sets/) if your data is static.